# Infinite scaling with lambda and mysql ends up with wrong data

Tags: node.js, architecture, aws-lambda, scaling, amazon-sqs

we are trying infinite scalibility and to make our processes fast using serverless architecture and make use of AWS sqs on top of lambdas

our data is a chain of mutations which is building on top of each other based on an id.

```
id  productId    eventDate   eventValue    balance
 1    1          2018-09-01    100          100
 2    1          2018-09-01    100          200
```

As you can see it take balance from previous row add event value in it and get the new balance this much is easy and every new value comes from sqs which triggers a lambda and our process then calculate value and add an entry into our event table. problem is when multiple messages kicks in it spawn multiple lambdas and they all look for previous row and we end up with the last stored record and end up something like

```
id  productId    eventDate   eventValue    balance
 1    1          2018-09-01    100          100
 2    1          2018-09-01    100          200
 3    1          2018-09-01    100          300
 4    1          2018-09-01    100          300
 5    1          2018-09-01    100          300
```

the issue is they all thought that their previous row balance is 200 so they added their event value in it and the calculation went wrong.

We can bundle the input and execute the operation one by one but this would completely kill the purpose of scaling and in the long run would make things really slow with a large input. optimistic locking doesn't seem to be helping us either because its a new entry based on a previous entry.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your table seems to be append only and the way you are calculating the balance is wrong because you may have multiple records being inserted concurrently and using the same data.

You could store the balance in another table where you update it by running an update query like this:
`UPDATE table SET balance = balance + ? WHERE product_id = ?`